# create vectors using exponent/power for numbers using prime powers

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create vectors for every number up to n by just using the exponents of the prime numbers, using prime vector PV=[2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29] to recognize each number and store these vectors for later calculations. My PVE=[k k k k k k k k k k x], with k being the exponents corrisponding to PV, and x is the exponent of any prime that PV does not divide, so x will always be 0 or 1 because my n is 960=(31^2)-1. So if any number in this set divides some number 9, for instance the vector exponent of 9 would be [0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] as 3^2 is 9. and the vector for 22 would be [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0] and this is 2*11=22. so every "numba" as in my program from 2 to n would have a prime vector exponent (PVE). This comes from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic that every number can be expressed as the product of primes, and it is unique.

Could you please look at my program to see what I am doing wrong to get the exponents.
Program:

```
n=960

for numba=2:n
    for c=2:numba-1


    if numba==2
        c=2


    if mod(numba,c)~=0
        numba=p

    end
    end
end

end

for k=1:9




PVEC=[2^k 3^k 5^k 7^k 11^k 13^k 17^k 19^k 23^k 29^k]

if p>29


if mod(numba,PVEC)==0
 max(PVEC,k) &  PVE==[k k k k k k k k k k 0]


    if mod(numba,PVE)~=0

    PVE=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]

    end
end



end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute `PVE` for each `numba` in one line, using [`factors`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/factor.html) and [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
PVE = histc(factor(numba),[PV inf])
```

Example:

```
>> PV = [2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29];
>> numba = 22;
>> PVE = histc(factor(numba),[PV inf])
PVE =
     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
>> numba = 9;
>> PVE = histc(factor(numba),[PV inf])
PVE =
     0     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks Luis!! i believed you have answered one of my previous questions, i wish i had the background in matlab like you, I am just novice. one question what is the inf in the program? is that to extend my vector by 1 0?

Comment: @Crisp `inf` is (positive) infinity. I included it so that the last entry in `PVE` catches any primes above 29, with their multiplicities (exponents)

Comment: Hi Luis, the inf i realize just assigns any prime greater than 29, just to the 29 column, so the inf is just technically adding an extra columns of zeros while using 29 to represent primes > 29. how could this be fixed. i have used a similar technique you have showed me with the set diff primes to get the last column to represent if there is any prime above 29, but to no avail, but thanks for all your help!!! i will continue to work on it.

Comment: @Crisp The `inf` adds a column _after_ the 29 column

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do in your first loop, but if I were you, I would use recursion to get an exponent. Something like this...

```
function [ expo ] = get_exponent( p, num, depth )
% return the exponent
% p: prime number
% num: number to be analyzed
% depth: depth of the recursion

    if p==1,
        error ('Do not use 1 for p!!')
    end

    if mod(num,p) == 0,
        depth = depth+1;
        expo = get_exponent(p, num/p, depth);
    else
        expo = depth;
    end

end
```

This `get_exponent` function returns the exponent for some number `num` of some prime `p`. For example,

```
>> get_exponent(5,325,0)
ans =
     2
>> get_exponent(13,325,0)
ans =
     1
```

Use this function in your second loop to get exponent of each prime.

Comment: Oh the first part of the code was just trying to define what a prime number is, i might not even use it. I will try what you say.